# Are all projectiles affected by gravity in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

So, as the games documentation cleary states that, everything is affected by gravity.  Well, I was in the Apache the other day and landed on one of the buildings at a flag post and seated the gunner position.  I fired off in the distance, and it appeared that there was no bullet drop at all.  I sat there a good 10 minutes (not being useful to my teammates at all) just shooting and watching bullets.  Asside from a bit of variation of in where the bullets left the barrel of the gun, it looked as if the bullets straightlined past the game's viewing distance.  With any other gun/device, given enough distance, you can clearly see gravity take affect after some distance.  Am I examining this wrong, or **is there anything else that is does this?**

Comment: Does the battlefield series use hitscan weapons?

Comment: I would guess that the helicopter gun is probably extremely powerful, thus there would not be a lot of bullet drop anyway, not unless you were shooting at the sun.

Comment: Well, like anything else, theres initial velocity vs mass vs wind resistance vs gravity.  Assuming DICE takes all these things into consideration (big assumption, i know), I don't think the bullets are comming out much faster than say, the M98B, which has very noticeable bullet drop past 500m.

Comment: @RavenDreamer, I am not sure.  Woulndn't know how to tell.

Comment: @hydroparadise [See this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/what-kind-of-weapon-is-a-hitscan-weapon)

Comment: @hydroparadise:  There is no wind-resistance in BF3.  And in both BF3 and the real-world, without wind-resistance, mass and initial-velocity (assuming you're shooting parallel with the ground) have no influence on the bullet drop-rate.  The only thing that matters is gravity *(which, interestingly enough, differs for different projectiles in BF3)*.  Note that the drop **amount** *is* affected by initial-velocity - the faster the bullet gets there, the less time it has to drop.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's wind resistance that causes a bullet to go from super-sonic to sub-sonic during its flight (at least in real life).  .22 caliber rifles exhibit this behaviour quite frequent.  True it does't affect the rate of drop, but it does affect the overall path and distance the projectile travels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://symthic.com/?s=bf3), the bullet-drop on gun-projectiles varies from gun-to-gun

> Bullet drop is -15 m/s for all the weapons except for AS VAL and all sniper rifles (excluding SKS) its -9.81 m/s
>   Shotgun shells have their own drops which are mentioned at the chart.

I can't find any information about bullet-drop for vehicle projectiles, but it's not unreasonable to believe they also have separate drop-rates.  *I'll update this answer if I find more info.*

Anecdotally, I can state with near certainty that the helicopter and AA projectile-drop-rates are much less than the other guns, possibly non-existent.

Comment: Im pretty certain that I witness bullet drop with the rocket pods. (if this counts as a bullet). The machinegun on a plane seems non existant. since the cross hairs always hit from a far distance.

Comment: Rockets do count as projectiles, but the bullets dont seem to have any drop.